# Pandas dot Object

Tags: python, pandas, theory

Why does A work, but not B?

(A)

```
inventory['in_stock'] = inventory.quantity.apply(lambda x: 'True' if x > 0 else 'False')
```

(B)

```
inventory.in_stock = inventory.quantity.apply(lambda x: 'True' if x > 0 else 'False')
```

When creating a column, why can't we use dot object? Is it because it doesn't pass through? Keen to understand the theory behind this.

Comment: BTW `inventory['in_stock'] = inventory.quantity.apply(lambda x: x > 0)` should be enough if you want to get boolean value

Answer (score 0):

Yes at some point you are right. A new column is not a part of dataframe so you can not get access to a column with ". call"

Answer (score 0):

i think you know when should we use the `dot (.)` notation and when to use the `square brackets ([])` 
if not ,
then you should know that when you are calling something then you use the `dot(.)`

notation and adding a new column to the data frame you should use the `square brackets ([])`